# Distance from $f(x)$ to $L_2^0[-1,1]$ and $ L_2 [-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $\mathbb{H}=L_2[-1,1]$ and let
> $$L_2^0[-1,1]=\left \{ f\in L_2[-1,1]:\int_{[-1,1]}f(x)dx=0 \right \}$$
> Is the subspace $L_2^0[-1,1]$ closed? Find $(L_2^0[-1,1])^{\bot}$. Find the projection of the function $f(x)=\sin x/x$ onto $L_2^0[-1,1]$ and the distance from $f(x)$ to $L_2^0[-1,1]$ and $ L_2[-1,1]$

I defined closedness because it is the kernel of a continuous linear functional, the orthogonal complement of which is a constant. I also found the projection of the function equal to $\sin x/x - c$, where $c$ is a constant such that $\int \sin x/x \; dx$ by $[-1,1]$ is equal to $2c$

But I don't understand how I can find $(L_2^0[-1,1])^{\bot}$ and distance from $f(x)$ to $L_2^0[-1,1]$ and $ L_2 [-1,1]$. Could you show me how to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the orthogonal complement, note that for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every $f\in L_2^0([-1,1])$ it is the case that:
$$\langle f,c\rangle=c\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=0$$ So $\mathbb{R}\subset (L_2^0([-1,1]))^\perp$. However, it is clear that for every $g\in L_2$, you can write $g=(g-\frac{\int_{-1}^1g(x)dx}{2})+\frac{\int_{-1}^1g(x)dx}{2}$ which gives us a decomposition:
$$L_2([-1,1])=L_2^0([-1,1])\oplus \mathbb{R}$$ So the codimension of $L_2^0([-1,1])$ is $1$, hence $\mathbb{R}= (L_2^0([-1,1]))^\perp$ (the constant functions).

As for the distance from subspace $X$, Im assuming the meaning is:
$$\inf_{g\in X}\|f-g\|$$
In that case, the distance of $f$ from $L_2$ is $0$ as it is an element of $L_2$. To calculate the distance from the closed subspace $L_2^0$, it is a standard result that the infimum is obtained by:
$$\|f(x)-P_{L_2^0}(f)\|$$
with $P_{L_2^0}$ being the orthogonal projection onto the subspace. To calculate $f(x)-P_{L_2^0}(f)$ is the same as calculating $P_{(L_2^0)^\perp}(f)=P_{\mathbb{R}}(f)$ (the projection onto the subspace of constant functions) which is easy as we have an orthonormal basis of the subspace of constant functions which is $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$. So:
$$P_{\mathbb{R}}(f)=\langle f,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and from here you can continue the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

For   a unit element $v$ in a real Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ let $$\mathcal{H}_0=\{x\in \mathcal{H}\,:\,\langle x,v\rangle =0\}$$ Thus by definition $\mathcal{H}_0=v^\perp.$ Hence $\mathcal{H}_0^\perp =\mathbb{R}v.$ Every element $x\in \mathcal{H}$ admits the orthogonal decomposition $$x=\langle x,v\rangle v+(x-\langle x,v\rangle v)$$ where the summands belong to $\mathcal{H}_0^\perp $ and $\mathcal{H}_0,$ respectively. The norm of the first element, i.e. $|\langle x,v\rangle|,$ represents the distance from $x$ to $\mathcal{H}_0.$

In the OP case $v=2^{-1/2}\bf{1}$ and $\mathcal{H}=L^2(-1,1).$